# How do I extract only the second string in a div among three different strings

Tags: html, web-scraping, scrapy, css-selectors

I [[image: snapshot of source code of a website]]

I want to extract the second text from the div.

I used

```
response.css(div.ml-1::text).get()
```

but it only returns the first parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
response.css(div.ml-1::text).getall()
```

Which will return list that you can index.

For example:

```
print(response.css(div.ml-1::text).getall()[1])
```

output:

```
"125"
```